# Not sure how to write postgresql query using CASE?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: `allPossible` and `actualSales`

```
SELECT * FROM allPossible;

  fullname1   | productid1  
--------------+------------  
 Bob Moore    |          2  
 Bob Moore    |          1  
 Kiera Origi  |          2  
 Kiera Origi  |          1  
 Jessica Lan  |          2  
 Jessica Lan  |          1  

SELECT * FROM actualSales;

  fullname2   | productid2 | quantity  
--------------+------------+----------  
 Bob Moore    |          2 |       10  
 Jessica Lan  |          2 |        4  
 Kiera Origi  |          1 |        5  
 Jessica Lan  |          1 |        6
```

I'd like to write a select query that outputs a table with the same structure as `allPossible`, but with an extra case attribute that is equal to quantity if `fullName1 = fullName2` and `productid1 = productid2`. If this is not true then the case attribute should equal 0.
To clarify, I want the output table to look like this:

```
  fullname1   | productid1  | case  
--------------+-------------+------  
 Bob Moore    |          2  |  10  
 Bob Moore    |          1  |   0  
 Kiera Origi  |          2  |   0  
 Kiera Origi  |          1  |   5  
 Jessica Lan  |          2  |   4  
 Jessica Lan  |          1  |   6
```

My issue is joining the two input tables properly so that I can use `CASE` to compare values from both tables. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an outer join. If the join doesn't match, you can use `coalesce()` to turn the NULL value into a zero:

```
select ap.*, 
       coalesce(act.quantity, 0) as quantity
from allpossible ap
  left join actualsales act 
         on act.fullname2 = ap.fullname1
        and act.productid2 = ap.productid1
```

This can also be achieved using a CASE expression:

```
select ap.*, 
       case 
         when act.quantity is null then 0 
         else act.quantity
       end as quantity
from allpossible ap
  left join actualsales act 
         on act.fullname2 = ap.fullname1
        and act.productid2 = ap.productid1
```